# Salesforce1 Record actions bar - how to add custom actions

Tags: salesforce1-app

In Salesforce1 app, on an Account record there is a Phone, Map, Website and Link icon on the Record Actions Bar. See below screenshot

[image]

I have a custom object for which I want to add a similar icon like Phone and Map. I tried looking in the developer guide and was not able to find any way to do it. Do you know if it is supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible to add extra options to that specific part of the UI. Try voting on this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzn6AAA) if you want this to be available in the future.

You could try adding a [Custom Button](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_enterprise.htm&language=en_US) in which case a drop-down will appear next to your Edit and Delete buttons with any additional buttons you've added. Alternatively you can use a [Publisher Action](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_actions.htm&language=en_US) which will allow you to perform your action from the '+' icon in the bottom right corner on the record detail page.

> The publisher actions feature lets you create actions and add them to the Chatter publisher on the home page, on the Chatter tab, in Chatter groups, and **on record detail pages**. You can also customize the order in which the standard Chatter actions appear, including Post, File, Link, and Poll.

Comment: do you know why certain publisher actions dont appear? Are there any settings apart from adding it to the page layout that needs to be done?

Comment: FYI - I have voted for the idea that you gave below, I think it will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to customize this action bar:

[image]

See the [release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_actionbar_customization.htm#rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_actionbar_customization) that explains about this update.